# Find last 24 hours executed commands per each user in bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, bash-scripting

How can I find last 24 hours executed commands per each user and mail them the result? I have Ubuntu GNU/Linux. I find out that I need a package named 'acct'. I have already installed and enabled that package using the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install acct
sudo accton on`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the "lastcomm" command and use the '--user' option for each. You'll have to parse it for the date range you want. Then send the output by your favorite MTA.